# Convert string into link javascript object used for mustache template

Tags: javascript, mustache

I have an object which have a property with a value of string.

```js
var notificationDetails = {
  dangerMessage: "I love basketball and love to watch it in. <a href='www.nba.com'>Link</a>;",
  seats: "1 seatRemaining",
  pName: "Item 1",
  class: ""
};

document.write(notificationDetails.dangerMessage);
```

How can I convert the a element  to a link in the dangerMessage property, it reads as string not the actual link. Thank you in advance.

I forgot to say that i am using mustache.js to render that property in the object it looks like this

```
<script type="text/x-mustache-tmpl" id="order-template">
     <div>{{dangerMessage}} </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Looks like a link to me.

Comment: It's working  , [link](https://jsfiddle.net/4n2vcy6s/)

Comment: I forgot to say that i am using mustache.js to render that property in the object it looks like this  <script type="text/x-mustache-tmpl" id="order-template">
                     <div>{{dangerMessage}} </div>
               </script>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comment, you can use `{{{dangerMessage}}}`:

```
<script type="text/x-mustache-tmpl" id="order-template">
  <div>{{{dangerMessage}}}</div>
</script>
```

From [Doc](http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html):

> All variables are HTML escaped by default. If you want to return
>   unescaped HTML, use the triple mustache: {{{name}}}.

Comment: Am I missing something? What does your code have to do with the actual post? And why did you tagged `mustache`?

Comment: @Ionut - the code here actually works (You're missing the comment where the OP stated theyre using mustache)

Comment: @Jamiec, ok. Sorry, my bad. Missed that. +1

Comment: @Ionut easy enough - they did add it as a comment after the fact. Never bothered to put that in the question or tags or title.

Comment: @Jamiec Yeah, me too was wondering, but later caught once I saw the comment!

Answer (score 0):

It works.

Look at the result of the code snippet below.

```js
var notificationDetails = {
  dangerMessage: "I love basketball and love to watch it in. <a href='www.nba.com'>Link</a>;",
  seats: "1 seatRemaining",
  pName: "Item 1",
  class: ""
};

document.write(notificationDetails.dangerMessage);
```

**EDIT for mustache.js:**
To have **unescaped html** you just need to use **triple** brackets `{{{ }}}` instead of double brackets `{{ }}` for escaped html:

`<div>{{{dangerMessage}}}</div>`

[Docs](http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html)

Comment: This is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.innerHtml`property of DOM elements:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var notificationDetails = {
           dangerMessage: "I love basketball and love to watch it in. <a href='www.nba.com'>Link</a>;",
           seats: "1 seatRemaining",
           pName:  "Item 1",
           class:""
     };
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = notificationDetails.dangerMessage;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to change my HTML content (innerHTML).</p>
```

Check this page: https://jsfiddle.net/o8nzwxt1/

Comment: You realise the edit I made was to make this runnable *in the answer itself* - negating the need for an external link to jsfiddle.